# Visual Studio Express 2010 on x86-64: libcmt.lib missing

Tags: compile, librarylink, ccompilerdriver

[The CCompilerDriver documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html) explains that to use visual studio express on 64-bit targets, it's necessary to install the windows SDK after installing visual studio. I have done this, first installing visual studio express 2010 and then installing v7.1 of the windows SDK. However, I still have a problem due to a missing LIBCMT.LIB

> ```
> Compiler`$CCompilerOptions={"ShellOutputFunction"->Print};
> cFun=Compile[{{x}},x^2, CompilationTarget->"C"];
> ```

```
C:\Users\lev\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\lev-think-5052\Working-lev-think-5052-7032-1>call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64 

Setting SDK environment relative to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\.
Targeting Windows 7 x64 Debug

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

compiledFunction0.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:compiledFunction0.dll 
/dll 
/implib:compiledFunction0.lib 
/implib:C:\Users\lev\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\lev-think-5052\Working-lev-think-5052-7032-1\compiledFunction0.lib 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\lib" 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64" 
ml64i3m.lib 
/out:C:\Users\lev\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\lev-think-5052\Working-lev-think-5052-7032-1\compiledFunction0.dll 
compiledFunction0.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
```

Has anyone managed to get this configuration working? How about with visual studio express 2008 and v7.0 of the SDK?

It took me several tries to get even this far, because I made the mistake of letting windows update install SP1 for visual studio express and this prevented installing the SDK, and I had had uninstall and reinstall everything a few times (it's not possible to simply uninstall SP1), so it's possible I've messed up my installation somehow. I can see that there is a LIBCMT.LIB in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib` which I presume is a 32-bit version of the library and not what the linker is looking for in this case.

Comment: Without being able to give a solution, I would like to mention that when I tried it on Windows 7 64 bit it was enough to install the Windows SDK (making sure to select the command line compiler for installation).  Without any additional configuration and *without* installing Visual Studio Express, `Compile[..., CompilationTarget -> "C"]` is working correctly.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm going to try uninstalling everything and then installing only the Windows SDK, since this works for you. Do you have v7.0 or v7.1?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that computer here, so I can't check.  But I have downloaded the latest version less than a month ago.  I am not knowledgeable about these things, I just thought it might be useful for you if I mention that it worked without extra setup for me.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did as you suggested and installed only v7.1 of the SDK and `Compile[..., CompilationTarget -> "C"]`seems to be working correctly now, so thanks. I'd still be interested if anybody knows if it's possible to have this working with visual studio also installed, though.

Comment: I remember I do get an error (visible with `"ShellOutputFunction"`) when `SetEnv.cmd` is run by Mathematica, but this did not seem to cause any trouble so far.

Comment: 64 bit libraries are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64`, one directory level deeper. Try adding this path you the `LIB` environment variables. When VS is installed, the `INCLUDE` and `LIB` paths are not set system-wide; instead, there are `.bat` files that set up specific environments. These do not apply to Mathematica, so I think your best bet is to set the environment vars by hand. (For the SDK, set LIB to something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\x64`).

Comment: @kkm it is there now, but somehow installing things in the order recommended by wolfram (first VS express and then win SDK) leaves you without the amd64 versions of the libraries. Or at least that's what seemed to happen to me....

Comment: I think that what happened was that somehow you did not select enough options when installing the SDK. It has a formidable feature selection screen, and... I guess just something happened there. Installing SDK over VS is the MS' recommended way of doing things as well, so this order is probably the most commonly tested scenario in the world.

Comment: @kkm Perhaps, but I did check every possible option on that feature selection screen. The SDK did throw up a screen about the compilers being already installed from VS express, but indicated that this was expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd share.

I had the same problem after re-installing VS2010 Ultimate (I also have 2008).

To fix it, I copied the following

- libcmt.lib
  libcmt.pdb
  libcmtd.lib
  libcmtd.pdb
  oldnames.lib

**from** C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib
**to** C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well, this could just as easily break VS 10 (or rather, the programs compiled with it). The link libraries are version-specific. If your program crashes, that would be the least of your problems. Subtle bugs and unpredictable behavior are a more likely result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Repairing or reinstalling VS 2010 express didn't work either. Most of the lib files where missing. I ended up installing on another pc and copying the missing files. Then it worked like a charm. Hope this helps.